# Combine 3 dataframe with different number of column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 3 data frame. 2 of them are only one column, another one is two columns.
3 dataframe looks like this

```
Itemcode Itemcode2     Itemcode  count
AAC         AAC           AAC      2
AAB         AAB           AAB      1
AAG         AAF           AAT      0
AAD         AAD           AAD      1
AAC                       AAF      1
```

If I want to check how many occurence of Itemcode and Itemcode2, I can use `value_counts()`.
Then if I want to combine them, I can not use pd.concat ([]) for the 3rd (it works if for 1 and 2 dataframe) because number of column is different.
How do I join these 3 data frame ?

This is the result I expected.

```
      df      df2    df3     
AAC    2       1      2
AAB    1       1      1
AAT    0       0      0
AAD    1       1      1
AAF    0       1      1
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can certainly use [`pandas.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
(pd.concat([df1['Itemcode'].value_counts(), 
            df2['Itemcode2'].value_counts(), 
            df3.set_index('Itemcode')
           ], axis=1, keys=['df1', 'df2', 'df3'])
   .droplevel(1, axis=1)
   .fillna(0, downcast='infer')
 )
```

Alternative without `value_counts` and with a `pivot_table`:

```
(pd.concat([df1, df2.rename(columns={'Itemcode2': 'Itemcode'}), df3], keys=['df1', 'df2', 'df3'], names=['source'])
   .reset_index(0)
   .fillna({'count': 1})
   .pivot_table(index='Itemcode', columns='source',
                values='count', aggfunc='sum', fill_value=0)
 )
```

Output:

```
     df1  df2  df3
AAC    2    1    2
AAB    1    1    1
AAG    1    0    0
AAD    1    1    1
AAF    0    1    1
AAT    0    0    0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df3 = df3.set_index('Itemcode').rename(columns={'count':'df3'})
a=df1.Itemcode.value_counts().rename('df1').to_frame()
b=df2.Itemcode2.value_counts().rename('df2').to_frame()
final=a.join(b).join(df3,how='right').fillna(0)
final

Itemcode    df1 df2 df3
AAC         2.0 1.0 2
AAB         1.0 1.0 1
AAT         0.0 0.0 0
AAD         1.0 1.0 1
AAF         0.0 0.0 1
```